# Managing and enhancing style items within a list view

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to sort out and leave a little prettier my items in my list view but can not, are always glued to the separating lines and looks very bad. I leave my code and screen as seen at this time

Layout

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EditText01"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Layout for adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtAsiento"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtTicket"
    android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtNombre"
    android:text="" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtNumero"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_green_small"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:maxHeight="48dp"
    android:maxWidth="80dp"
    android:text="Validar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNombre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTicket"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtNombre"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNumero"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtTicket"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtTicket"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtAsiento"
    android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: img]

Comment: Try adding some margin to the top and bottom?

Comment: Oh yes, I've tried a lot but still looks well. @jyoon

Comment: Did you try adding margins in the adapter?

Comment: @jyoon Yes, this works for me but messy, do not make very well.

Comment: I don't quite understand you.

Comment: My whole view is deformed when I margin from the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding margins to the top and bottom of your adapter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:marginTop="10dp"
android:marginBottom="10dp" >

...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom` would also work (slightly differently).